# Auto Increment id 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whilst creating a few users on phpmyadmin(noscripts), I noticed that auto incrementing was not working. It's always setting the id to 0. Not sure why. Anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: What is the column's definition?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable`.

Comment: Did you do it manually (I mean, with GUI interface) ?

Comment: I did do it manually using the insert tab on phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason for auto increment not working is when your table doesn't have the column auto increment. You need to alter your table this way:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Well it is not the only possible reason, it just happened to my too and I am 200% sure the field is set as AUTO_INCREMENT. I guess there can be some odd bug too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your table then click on structure and make id primary. This should do the trick.